# Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer are displaying incorrect favicon

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, favicon, ico

I have searched stackoverflow and many other websites

Nothing seems like fixing the problem

The website link : https://www.monstermmorpg.com

The source code in header

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/favicon-32x32.png">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/android-chrome-192x192.png">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/favicon-16x16.png">

<link rel="manifest" href="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/site.webmanifest">

<link rel="mask-icon" href="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#490f1e">

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/favicon.ico">

<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#00aba9">

<meta name="msapplication-config" content="//static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/browserconfig.xml">

<meta name="theme-color" content="#272727">
```

It should display this favicon : https://static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/favicon.ico

for example this is how it is seen in chrome

[image]

However in internet explorer, microsoft edge it is always displayed like below

How to fix?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are having an issue with the IE 11 and MS Edge legacy browser.

I try to visit your site and I can see the issue there.

I suggest you add **rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"** and **rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon"** attributes in your code and again test the issue.

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/favicon.ico"/>
</head>
<body>
Hello World...
</body>
</html>
```

It resolves the issue on my end and I can see the correct favicon in the IE and MS Edge browser.

Output in the IE 11 browser:

[image]

Output in the MS Edge legacy browser:

[image]

Note:

1. Try to clear the cache and history of the IE and Edge browser after making changes to your site.
2. If the issue persists then try to move the favicon.ico to the root folder of your site and modify the new path in your site and again test the issue.

Let us know about your test results.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer but still not working. You can test yourself now. I have added even full path instead of relative still not working. You will see in the code <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/favicon.ico"> and <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/favicon.ico"> but still not working. I have cleared entire browsing history.

Comment: you can also test on this pretty tiny page. i checked from developer tools network tab, no icon is requested https://www.monstermmorpg.com/Monster-Picture.aspx?Monster=Arctle

Comment: Removed other links and now no favicon is displayed at all

Comment: final edit. After i removed all other links, it worked fine. so browser is using one of the other links which one i don't know.

Comment: This icon link is working for the IE and the Edge browser. https://static.monstermmorpg.com/favicons/favicon.ico you can use this with the suggested code in the answer may help to fix the issue.

Comment: I have found the answer. It was using 32x32 pixel version. After i have updated 32 pixel image now it shows as i want. Thank you